# How do I upgrade my booster storage?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

5 slots per booster is simply not enough, especially when turning in lots of salvage. How do I hold more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one way to increase this by 10(!) is to acquire the Bassani Butchers deed in Mor Ardain. You can get this at development level 1.

You can increase it by an additionall 10 by getting the Hanoon Deeds (Hanoon Fishmongers, Mor Ardain, not sure on dev level).